# Joomla site slow after connecting to firewall

Tags: joomla, firewall

I have a Joomla site developed in version Joomla! 3.2.0 Stable. The site load time 5 or 6 seconds if the network in not connected to firewall. But after connecting to firewall the load time goes up and it is almost 5 to 6 minutes. I have checked my server log and there is no SYN_FLOOD message. Could any one please help me?

Comment: This is absolutely impossible to answer. What do you mean by *network in not connected to firewall* or connected to firewall? What firewall? How? What have you done to configure things? We need detail. I am concerned about the 5-6 second response time, however, you clearly have a routing issue with the 5-6 minutes. Cheers!!

Comment: Actually I tell you the scenario we are using sophos firewall and our old site works well in one server and it is already configured in firewall... what we tried is we developed a new website in joomla in a different server and disconnected the network cable of the old server and used the public IP of the old server in our new server. Also in our new server we used the same gateway,mask and dns as in our old server. We didnt change any firewall configuration as the old site was working properly. But our new site is very slow and the load time is very high.